Should we allow unregistered users to post questions and answers?
Near the start of 2022, a change was implemented which required users to be registered to post on Arqade. This was done to combat a network wide spamming problem, and it was supposed to be temporary, but it ended up (accidently) becoming permanently instead. We reached out to the CM team, and they informed us that we could reallow posts from unregistered users at any time.
This naturally raises the question: Do we even want to allow unregistered users to post questions and answers on Arqade? And, as usual, the mod team wants to get input from the community at large about this decision.
Should we allow unregistered users to post questions and answers on Arqade?

Since the community is in favour of the suggestion made by MBraedley, we've gone ahead and had Stack Exchange re-enable posting from unregistered users on the site. In January we'll review the data, and then make a new meta to revisit this discussion.

From watching spam on Smoke Detector I would say spammers generally register these days. There is a spam wave hitting GIS this morning from a very persistent spammer using registered users.

Can we run an experiment with it off for a month?  I would suggest mid-December to mid-January to capture some Christmas traffic.  If we see a spike in spam without a lot of good quality anonymous posts or vice-versa not a lot of spam with a bunch of good quality anonymous posts, then we have our answer.

I've reached out to the CM team to see if doing this is possible. I suspect yes, and I hope yes, since I really like this idea.

So.. with it "on", I presume? 'It' being allowing unregistered users to post.

CM team said doing this is possible, and they can even help us gather data

Since the registration requirement was implemented in early 2022 as a temporary measure to combat network-wide spam and the Community Managers simply forgot to remove it after the spam wave subsided, I believe we should return to allowing unregistered users to post.
I believe that our community has an active set of reviewers that can handle spam or low-quality posts. If we encounter another overwhelming spam wave that proves too difficult for our community to manage, we could always request that the CMs temporarily reinstate the registration requirement again.
Allowing unregistered users to participate would likely increase overall site activity through more questions and answers, creating additional opportunities for voting and rep gain. These unregistered users may well become regular contributors to our community; see also this relevant meta discussion: "Do one-rep unregistered users contribute positively to Arqade?"
Looking at precedent across the SE network, Science Fiction & Fantasy SE has successfully maintained an open posting policy. Despite having a more permissive posting policy than Arqade, allowing memory-based identification questions, they effectively maintain their content quality while welcoming unregistered users. Their success suggests we could handle a similar approach.

As a counterpoint, some problems can't be fixed by reviewers. For example, there are plenty of unregistered users that get locked out of their accounts, even when they're using the same email. Some of these users may post a non answer instead of a comment/edit (which review will clean up), but rarely do they find their way back to their original account, which likely limits their activity. (I've seen these accidental second accounts happen dozens of times, especially on SFF.)

@Laurel Mods can actually merge accounts when this happens, although most mergers are due to sock puppets breaking rules.
